# Change of variables for a PDF of angles (circular/wrapped data)

Tags: data-transformation, density-function, circular-statistics

I have a PDF with angle $\theta$ as the independent variable: $R(\theta)$. $\theta$ is defined up to mod $\pi$ -- accordingly, $R(\theta) = R(\theta + \pi)$. I need to express this PDF as a function of a different independent variable, $\psi$. $\psi$ and $\theta$ are related by a constant offset, i.e. $\psi = \theta + C$, where the mod $\pi$ requirement still applies.

How can I perform this change of variables? Is there anything subtle to consider here because of the mod $\pi$ behavior, or can I simply swap $\psi$ for $\theta$ in my PDF?

Comment: Wouldn't a standard change of variable put $\psi-C$ for $\theta$?

Comment: Yes, clearly $\theta = \psi - C$. The question is whether just doing that is valid with directional data

Comment: Mathematically, it's clearly correct (as long as you also deal with the implied domain for $\psi$ correctly). What you really seem to be asking is whether you can then legitimately shift the density for $\psi$ but perhaps I misunderstood something.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm asking. I believe this checks out because the Jacobian of the variable transformation is unity but wondering if I'm missing anything.